# Is there a way to prevent sliding window from freezing?

Tags: windows, winter

I have a window that slides to the side, and each time temperature outside drops below 0*C it freezes and there is no way to open it (not that there is ice all over it, just moisture from the room  freezes somewhere inside I guess). Are there any (easy) solutions to prevent freezing or making it open when needed?

Comment: What is the material of the window sash and frame (ie. Vinyl, wood, metal) and is it painted?

Comment: @ChrisP Looks like a vinyl frame and window (metal wrapped into vinyl?). Not painted.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to pull out the window and clean everything really well to make sure nothing is gumming things up.  Then I would use a clean rag and wipe all the areas where the window contacts the frame with a good quality silicone lubricant.  A little goes a long way with silicone lubricant, you don't need to saturate things with a direct blast.  I would avoid wd-40, or other cheap oil sprays, it could make things worse.

Comment: Chris is absolutely right on. Always use a dry silicone spray lube, never an oil based or WD40. This is very common in bathrooms where a lot of condensation forms on the windows. Wipe excessive moisture off the windows and frame whenever possible.

Comment: Really clean it well on a nice day, and flood with silicone lubricant? The stuff is quite hydrophobic so could prevent ice jams.

Answer (score 1):

As a QA Engineer for a local window and door company, researching some topics I stumbled across this post. Please check the humidity levels in the home (hopefully not too high). Make sure there is adequate air flow (open vents & curtains) in the room. And most of all, check the perimeter of the slider sash (operating/sliding portion) for a tight enough seal. This may include checking weatherstripping and critical measurements of the frame channel/pocket to slider/sash profile thickness.

Regards,
Sunny H

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to install a heating cable along the perimeter. When you need to open the window you heat it up so it unfreezes.